# How can I replace fragment inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity with a ViewPager, each page of the ViewPager has a Fragment.

Inside my `Screen3Fragment` I have a LinearLayout (`lly_fragments`) where I am showing some other fragments. I start by showing the fragment `Screen3_1`

```
public class Screen3Fragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentManager manager;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;


    public static Screen3Fragment newInstance() {
        final Screen3Fragment mf = new Screen3Fragment();
        return mf;
    }

    public Screen3Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen3, container, false);
        Screen3_1Fragment frag31 = new Screen3_1Fragment();
        manager = getChildFragmentManager();
        transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.lly_fragments,frag31,"frag31");
        transaction.addToBackStack("frag31");
        transaction.commit();
        return v;
    }

}
```

This works fine without problems. Problem comes when, from within `frag31` (which is inside Screen3Fragment), I want to call `fragt32`, for that I do the following.

```
public class Screen3_1Fragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageButton imgbt_timer;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen3_1,container,false);
        imgbt_timer = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.bT_scr31_timer);
        imgbt_timer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                            .replace(R.id.lly_fragments, new Screen3_2Fragment(), "frag32")
                                            .commit();
            }
        });


        return v;
    }
}
```

As I read in other answers, the line `transaction.replace`should do the trick and replace the existing `frag31` by the given `frag32` inside the same given container `lly_fragments`.

However, I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id.....` I am not sure why.

Comment: have a look at View.invalidate(). https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate() 

Not sure, but maybe this could help.

Comment: Use fragment manager, not child fragment manager. I think if you use child manager, you should use view id inside parent fragment.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin, thanks, I would appreciate a more elaborated answer, where should I use it?? in my `Screen3Fragment`??, in my `Screen3_1Fragment `?? in both of them??, and why? I read that when using fragments from within fragments you call child manager

Comment: Is working? I can post an answer.

Comment: well i did not try it since I do not know where to use it, trying all possible combinations will take me some time. And I would like to go straight to the right answer

Comment: ok using `getFragmentManager` instead `getChildFragmentManager` **ONLY** in my `Screen3_1Fragment ` works to go from frag31 to frag32. However, back button does not go back to `frag31` from `frag32`

Comment: Use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() to replace fragment inside fragment3

Answer (score 0):

`getFragmentManager()` will return always attributes from parent, in most cases the activities. `getChildFragmentManager()` wil return parent attributes (in your case, `Screen3Fragment` attributes). It should be used when you add a fragment inside a fragment.

In your case, `Screen3Fragment` should be added using `getFragmentManager()` and `Screen3_1Fragment` should be added using `getChildFragmentManager()` because `Screen3_1Fragment` is `Screen3Fragment` child. `Screen3Fragment` is the parent.

I recomand you to use always `getFragmentManager()` with `add` method, not `replace` because your parent will be the same.

`getChildFragmentManager()` can be used when you add a ViewPager inside a fragment.

Comment: ok, `Screen3Fragment` is the parent of both `Screen3_1Fragment ` and `Screen3_2Fragment`, so it does not need to be added or replaced.

Comment: Depending your implementation, i don't know how you did it.

Comment: ok I will play around with it and accept it, if I get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback, as following :
**that worked for me, I hope my answers helps you**

**1) create a interface**

```
  public interface ChangeFragmentListener {

    void onChangeFragmentLicked(int fragment);
}
```

**2) implement the interface and transaction methods in your activity:**

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChangeFragmentListener {


        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        Fragment1 fragment1;
        Fragment2 fragment2;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            fragment1.setChangeFragmentListener(this);

            fragment2 = new Fragment2();
            fragment2.setChangeFragmentListener(this);

            initListeners();
        }

    void changeToFrag1() {
            fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main_fragment_container,fragment1, "");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        void changeToFrag2() {
            fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main_fragment_container, fragment2, "");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

@Override
    public void onChangeFragmentLicked(int fragment) {
        switch (fragment){
            case 1:
                changeToFrag1();
                break;

            case 2:
                changeToFrag2();
                break;
        }
    }
```

**3) Create object from the interface to handle the callback:**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

   private ChangeFragmentListener changeFragmentListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);

        view.findViewById(R.id.fragment1_textView).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeFragmentListener.onChangeFragmentLicked(2);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public Fragment1 setChangeFragmentListener(ChangeFragmentListener changeFragmentListener) {
        this.changeFragmentListener = changeFragmentListener;
        return this;
    }
}
```